# SQL : select when a character occurs more than once in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement

```
select * from B2B_CardTechCards
        where Field NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

I only want to select the cells that has more than one occurrence of "-" in it. if it occurred once I don't need it.

Comment: `where Field LIKE '%-%-%'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply search for two of them:

```
select * from B2B_CardTechCards
where Field LIKE '%-%-%'
```

Comment: @yeah fine.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the count of `'-'` in `Field` column  by using

```
(len(Field) - len(replace(Field, '-', '')))
```

Now we can select rows that has the above count value more than one

```
select * 
from B2B_CardTechCards
where  (len(Field) - len(replace(Field, '-', ''))) > 1
```